# using JQuery can I replace an empty div with the result of a load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a placeholder div nested inside another div.
I want to replace the placeholder div with the data returned from a `.load()` call when the parent div is clicked on using it `onclick` function...

for example:

```
function accordianClick(projectId) {
         $("#project-placeholder-" + projectId).replaceWith(
               $.load("projectDetail?projectId=" + projectId));
}
```

The trick is I only want to fetch the data to be loaded if the placeholder div exists so once you click on the parent and replace it the first time it won't exist anymore therefore the load function will not be called.

For example this works but every-time I click the parent div it still fetches the data.

```
function accordianClick(projectId) {
    $.get("projectDetail?projectId=" + projectId, function(data) {
        $("#project-placeholder-" + projectId).replaceWith(data);
    }, 'html');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `length` to check if it exists.

```
function accordianClick(projectId) {
    var $container = $("#project-placeholder-" + projectId);
    if( $container.length > 0 ) {
        $.get("projectDetail?projectId=" + projectId, function(data) {
            $container.replaceWith(data);
        }, 'html');
    }
}
```